# Is there an exact example which show that the non-negativity in weak maximum principle is necessary?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, maximum-principle

We know that the **Weak Maximum Principle** assert that for an uniformly elliptic operator $L=a^{ij}(x)D_{ij}+b^i(x)D_i+c$, if $c\leq0$ and $Lu\geq0$ in a bounded domain $\Omega$, then $u$ attains on $\partial \Omega$ its non-negative maximum in $\Omega$.

I wonder whether there exists an exact  example show that with the same condition, $u$ may attains its negative maximum in the interior of $\Omega$?

Comment: What you're describing sounds a lot like the strong maximum principle, not the weak one.

Comment: Yes, you were right. I need to correct it!

Comment: Let $Lu=u''$ and $\Omega = (0,1)$. Then the function $u=x^2-x-1$ satisfies $L u>0$ in $\Omega$, however, $u(0)=u(1)=-1$, then there is something wrong with your statament of the weak maximum principle.

Comment: It's nothing wrong with the statement, since in you example, $u^+\equiv0$, hence $u^+$ attains its maximum in $\Omega$ at the boundary!